# iOS development with React Native or Flutter with minimal apple hardware

Tags: macos, react-native-ios, flutter-ios

Not sure if this has been asked before.

To target iOS for mobile development with react native or flutter, do I need to move my entire development machine to an apple one? I do know that for any serious iOS app development, I'd need to get a mac.

But is it possible to use mac machine minimally with the bulk of the development being done in my non-mac main machine?

For e.g. I'd buy a cheaper Mac mini with low specs to get the XCode, run iOS simulation and push the app to app store. And during development from my main machine, I'd somehow connect to this mac mini for iOS simulation.

Is it possible? I just don't wanna move my entire desktop usage over to a mac.

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna development in light machine use react native and use its expo cli . its very light you did not need to make build in Xcode and android studio

check expo documentation [here](https://expo.io/)

Comment: Say I wanna test my app in different iOS simulators. Is it possible to do this from a non-mac machine with expo?

Comment: you will test with your actual device only